# Publishing to Symbol Source from Team City

Tags: nuget, teamcity

For awhile in my [Team City build](https://teamcity.bixbots.com/viewLog.html?guest=1&buildId=320&buildTypeId=NCodeCompositionDisposableParts_Publish&tab=buildLog&state=&expand=all&filter=debug#_), I am unable to publish my source NuGet packages to symbolsource.org as it responds with `500 Internal Server Error`.

```
[16:02:36][push] Pushing NCode.Composition.DisposableParts 1.0.1 to the symbol server (http://nuget.gw.symbolsource.org/Public/NuGet)...
[16:04:18][push] Failed to process request. 'Internal Server Error'. 
[16:04:18][push] The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error..
[16:04:18][push] Process exited with code 1
```

I am able to publish my normal packages to NuGet.org just fine. I believe that I have properly configured everything as documented by symbol source.

- https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Wiki/Publishing
- http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet
- https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Account/Register

Here is my Build Step configuration for NuGet Publish:

- Runner Type: NuGet Publish
- NuGet.exe: Default 2.8.6
- Packages: *.nupkg
- API Key: (my personal API key from NuGet.org)
- Package Source: (blank)

In my build output directory and artifacts recognized by TeamCity, I do have both of my packages in there:

- NCode.Composition.DisposableParts.1.0.1.nupkg
- NCode.Composition.DisposableParts.1.0.1.symbols.nupkg

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with two packages with the same name. Did you try a workaround with another build configuration and snapshot dependency?
I'm using another build configuration with snapshot dependency to build which produces *.nupkg and *.symbol.nupkg. Artifact dependency is set to:

```
-:*.nupkg => <replace with location>
+:*.symbol.nupkg
```

The build configuration only publishes *.symbol.nupkg to symbolsource.org.